# How to tame the Windows headers (useful defines)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, macros, c-preprocessor

In one of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394132/macro-and-member-function-conflict) question [jalf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33213/jalf) spoke about useful define `NOMINMAX`, that could prevent from unwanted defining min/max macros. Are there other useful defines that can help to control `windows.h` (or other Windows headers, for instance Microsoft C Runtime headers or STL implementation) behavior?

Comment: Ugh.  I wasted half an hour on this nonsense of min and max on win32 platform.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The most commonly used is probably `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` - it disables rarely used parts of the API. You can find more on MSDN's [Using the Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28VS.85%29.aspx).

I remembered wrong about MSDN listing those defines, so here's list from windows.h:

```
/*  If defined, the following flags inhibit definition
 *     of the indicated items.
 *
 *  NOGDICAPMASKS     - CC_*, LC_*, PC_*, CP_*, TC_*, RC_
 *  NOVIRTUALKEYCODES - VK_*
 *  NOWINMESSAGES     - WM_*, EM_*, LB_*, CB_*
 *  NOWINSTYLES       - WS_*, CS_*, ES_*, LBS_*, SBS_*, CBS_*
 *  NOSYSMETRICS      - SM_*
 *  NOMENUS           - MF_*
 *  NOICONS           - IDI_*
 *  NOKEYSTATES       - MK_*
 *  NOSYSCOMMANDS     - SC_*
 *  NORASTEROPS       - Binary and Tertiary raster ops
 *  NOSHOWWINDOW      - SW_*
 *  OEMRESOURCE       - OEM Resource values
 *  NOATOM            - Atom Manager routines
 *  NOCLIPBOARD       - Clipboard routines
 *  NOCOLOR           - Screen colors
 *  NOCTLMGR          - Control and Dialog routines
 *  NODRAWTEXT        - DrawText() and DT_*
 *  NOGDI             - All GDI defines and routines
 *  NOKERNEL          - All KERNEL defines and routines
 *  NOUSER            - All USER defines and routines
 *  NONLS             - All NLS defines and routines
 *  NOMB              - MB_* and MessageBox()
 *  NOMEMMGR          - GMEM_*, LMEM_*, GHND, LHND, associated routines
 *  NOMETAFILE        - typedef METAFILEPICT
 *  NOMINMAX          - Macros min(a,b) and max(a,b)
 *  NOMSG             - typedef MSG and associated routines
 *  NOOPENFILE        - OpenFile(), OemToAnsi, AnsiToOem, and OF_*
 *  NOSCROLL          - SB_* and scrolling routines
 *  NOSERVICE         - All Service Controller routines, SERVICE_ equates, etc.
 *  NOSOUND           - Sound driver routines
 *  NOTEXTMETRIC      - typedef TEXTMETRIC and associated routines
 *  NOWH              - SetWindowsHook and WH_*
 *  NOWINOFFSETS      - GWL_*, GCL_*, associated routines
 *  NOCOMM            - COMM driver routines
 *  NOKANJI           - Kanji support stuff.
 *  NOHELP            - Help engine interface.
 *  NOPROFILER        - Profiler interface.
 *  NODEFERWINDOWPOS  - DeferWindowPos routines
 *  NOMCX             - Modem Configuration Extensions
 */
```

Comment: Link leads to the article which mention only WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN. Wrong link?

Comment: Hm, I though it lists NOxxx defines. I'll edit my answer to include that list.

Comment: The article also says to look in windows.h for more macros. ("For a list of support NOapi symbols, see Windows.h")
I don't think there is any complete reference documentation.

Comment: Well, that comment is apparently the only one. I could swear I saw this on MSDN somewhere, though.

Comment: This isn't a list of useful defines, it's a list of `NOXXX` defines. Most are useless. And `STRICT` isn't listed...

Comment: A few more:

    #define NOCRYPT
    #define NOTAPE
    #define NOIMAGE
    #define NOPROXYSTUB
    #define NORPC

Answer (score 6):

MFC projects can use `VC_EXTRALEAN` since `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is already defined by MFC. I also recommend [enabling STRICT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383731(VS.85).aspx).