# How to resolve it when class method and macro have the same name?

Tags: c++, macros

I have encountered a problem when I was upgrading a class and need to import an external library.

For example, I am editing a class called `CFoo`, which has a public method `SendMessage()`.
It works fine until I need to include a library - which contains a macro also named `SendMessage()`. It causes a complete mess to my current code because all part containing `SendMessage()` is being replaced by the macro.

I have found a similar question about macro naming collision:
[How do I avoid name collision with macros defined in Windows header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321713/how-do-i-avoid-name-collision-with-macros-defined-in-windows-header-files)

However in my case the public method name can't be changed as it is already released and used in other projects.

Is there a way not to use or include a specific macro, or to specify whether a macro or a method should be used when a function is called?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe you can call the member not the macro by using `(SendMessage)(args...)`.

Comment: @EJP Even the method definition got replaced by the marco since I am actually including the library in the class header file.

Comment: Then you are certainly going to need `#undef` at least at that point.

Answer (score 1):

If standard compliancy is not a requirement try the `push_macro`/`pop_macro` pragmas

```
#pragma push_macro("SendMessage")
#undef SendMessage
//your stuff
#pragma pop_macro("SendMessage")
```

It works on MSVC, GCC and CLANG

Answer (score 0):

I have a vague way to resolve it.

Check using `#ifdef`..

If so, undefine it using "`#undef`" before calling your function.

Comment: If I have multiple macro naming collision, do I have to `#undef` all of them?

Comment: Yes you do, and you don't need the `#ifdef`.

Comment: I am not sure of any other way. Also I am not sure if namespacing works. Try it and see.

Comment: namespacing doesn't work, macros are resolved before the namespaces.