# Two nearly identical files, one throws two errors and the other does not

Tags: c++

I have have 2 header files:

- color.h
- rgb.h

In the `color.h` file I have:

```cpp
#pragma once

class RGB;
class HSL;

class Color {
public:
  /** The alpha value of the color. */
  int a;

  static RGB rgb(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255);
  static HSL hsl(int h, int s, int l, int a = 255);
};
```

Then in my `rgb.h` file I have:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "color.h"

class Color;

class RGB : public Color {
public:
  int r;
  int g;
  int b;

  RGB(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255);
};
```

But for some reason this generates the following two errors, and I am not sure why.

1. declaration does not declare anything
2. macro "RGB" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 3

I also have another file called `hsl.h` Which is basically the same as the `rgb.h` file only it doesn't have those errors:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "color.h"

class Color;

class HSL : public Color {
public:
  int h;
  int s;
  int l;

  HSL(int h, int s, int l, int a = 255);
};
```

What is causing this?

Based on the second error, I feel like it is trying to override an existing class/constructor. I am using `#include <jpeglib.h>` in my `main.cpp` file, could that be declaring an RGB that I am accidentally attempting to override?

Here is the full error message:

```
C:\Users\untun\Documents\vscode\draw\draw\core\color/rgb.h:13:39: error: macro "RGB" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 3
   13 |   RGB(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255);
      |                                       ^
In file included from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/windows.h:71,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/rpc.h:16,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/objbase.h:7,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/shlwapi.h:14,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/jmorecfg.h:19,
                 from C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/jpeglib.h:31,
                 from C:\Users\untun\Documents\vscode\draw\draw\core\main.cpp:1:
C:/msys64/ucrt64/include/wingdi.h:1397: note: macro "RGB" defined here
 1397 | #define RGB(r,g,b) ((COLORREF)(((BYTE)(r)|((WORD)((BYTE)(g))<<8))|(((DWORD)(BYTE)(b))<<16)))
      | 
C:\Users\untun\Documents\vscode\draw\draw\core\color/rgb.h:13:3: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
   13 |   RGB(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255);
      |   ^~~
```

Comment: Likely unrelated, but `color.h` defines the class `Color`, you shouldn't have `class Color;` after including `color.h`.

Comment: Please update your question to include the full error messages, including the lines that are producing these errors. Sure the compiler is giving you some file/line number details for messages like `declaration does not declare anything`.

Comment: @user229044 I updated with the full error message

Comment: *What is causing this?* -- `#define RGB(r,g,b) ((COLORREF)(((BYTE)(r)|((WORD)((BYTE)(g))<<8))|(((DWORD)(BYTE)(b))<<16)))` -- There is an `RGB` macro in the Windows API that clashes with your `RGB` function.

Comment: I assumed something was clashing, how do I stop it from clashing? I think it is coming from the `jpeglib.h` library.

Comment: Maybe better dupe target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321713/how-do-i-avoid-name-collision-with-macros-defined-in-windows-header-files

Comment: The gist is that you should rename your class from `RGB` to something else.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am doing now `RGB` -> `RGBColor`.