# Unresolved External Symbol when using dllexport and specific function name

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport

**EDIT**

To get around the problem, I added the following to the (beginning of the) header file:

```
#ifdef GetMessage
#undef GetMessage
static inline BOOL GetMessage(
LPMSG lpMsg,
HWND hWnd,
UINT wMsgFilterMin,
UINT wMsgFilterMax
) {
#if UNICODE
return ::GetMessageW(lpMsg, hWnd, wMsgFilterMin, wMsgFilterMax);
#else
return ::GetMessageA(lpMsg, hWnd, wMsgFilterMin, wMsgFilterMax);
#endif
}
#endif
```

---

I'm creating a C++ DLL (using Visual Studio 2008) from code like the following:

Header File:

```
#include <windows.h> // Edit: This is the culprit.
class __declspec(dllexport) TestBaseClass
{
protected:
   char m_Message[512];
public:
   TestBaseClass();
   virtual char* GetMessage(void) = 0;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) TestDerivedClass : public TestBaseClass
{
public:
   TestDerivedClass();
   virtual char* GetMessage(void);
};
```

CPP File:

```
TestBaseClass::TestBaseClass()
{
}

TestDerivedClass::TestDerivedClass() : TestBaseClass()
{
}

char* TestDerivedClass::GetMessage(void)
{
   sprintf(m_Message, "This is a Message");
   return m_Message;
}
```

When I go to compile the DLL, I get a linker error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual char *
>   __thiscall TestDerivedClass::GetMessageA(void)" (?GetMessageA@TestDerivedClass@@UAEPADXZ)

If I change every instance of "GetMessage" to something else (e.g. "TestFunc"), I do not get the linker error.

**Primary Question**: Why can't I use "GetMessage" as my function name?

**Secondary Question**: Is there a way to resolve the linker error, and keep "GetMessage" in my class, as currently defined?

Comment: Compiled for me with VS 2005.  Is this a Windows app (with windows messages, etc.) or a straight Win32 DLL?  Can you generate a make file and post it?

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, the problem arises when #include-ing <windows.h>.

Comment: ewwww `char m_Message[512];`. MAGIC_BUFFER_SIZE much?

Comment: Caveat: it's not originally my code.  I agree with the sentiment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's due to a quirk in the Windows headers.  When you `#include <windows.h>`, it `#define`s the symbol `GetMessage` to either `GetMessageA` or `GetMessageW`, depending on whether or not you have Unicode support enabled (more specifically, if the `UNICODE` macro is defined) -- see [Unicode in the Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Conventions for Function Prototypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info on that.

To work around this, you have a few options:

- Don't include the Windows headers
- Define the macro [`NOMSG`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394910/how-to-tame-the-windows-headers-useful-defines) before include `<windows.h>` -- this will suppress the declarations of various message-related functions and macros
- `#undef GetMessage` before your class definition
- Rename your function to something else

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty standard preprocessor lossage.  Your identifier is getting whacked by a macro.  It lives inside the Windows headers, it renames the winapi GetMessage() function to either GetMessageA or GetMessageW, depending on whether UNICODE defined.

Pick another name or use #undef GetMessage

Comment: You have a typo: should be `#undef GetMessage`, not `#undef GetMessageA`, right?