# Calling function with parenthesis around its name using C++

Tags: c++

I found code in boost similar to:

```
class A
{
    stats stat;
public:
    int min() const{ return (stat.min)(); }
};

...

int stats::min()
{
...
}
```

Why are parenthesis here? I know that it can be used for "most vexing parse" and to prohibit ADL. But maybe something else? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean the `(stat.min)` in the `return (stat.min)();` statement? There's absolutely no need for them, except if the original coder didn't trust the operator precedence to do the right thing (which it does).

Comment: It doesn't do anything. They were probably in the habit of wrapping function names in parens to avoid ADL and they just ended up using them here too.

Comment: cross-reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24116817/819272

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's done because windows.h (Windows platform) has #defines for both min and max. See here for more info: [How to tame the Windows headers (useful defines)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394910/how-to-tame-the-windows-headers-useful-defines) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/13420838/297451

Comment: O ye! Thank you so much! I don't know if I can vote, but I would like to set you max ball!