# Disabling PlaySound() that is included by LibCURL

Tags: c++, raylib

I've been developing with raylib for quite a while now.

I've gotten libcurl to work, but it doesn't work with `windows.h`, because of the functions names overriding others.

However, there is a workaround, by mentioning these defines (in `curl.h`):

```
#define NOGDICAPMASKS - this disables CC_, LC_, PC_, CP_ TC_ RC_

#define NOVIRTUALKEYCODES - this disables VK_

#define NOWINMESSAGES - this disables WM_ EM_ LB_

#define NOWINSTYLES - this disables WS_, CS_, ES_, LBS_, SBS_, CBS_

#define NOSYSMETRICS - this disables SM_
```

the list goes on an on...

Keep in mind that I don't need these, I won't use any of these since I'm trying to make it as cross-platform as I can, only libcurl includes these BUT it doesn't use them in any way.

What I am asking is, where could I find a full list of these, and if not a define that STOPS the including of `PlaySound()`, `PlaySoundA()`, etc.. and other functions related to sound, since they are interferring with `PlaySound()` from raylib.

Comment: I am a little confused what libcurl has to do with raylib

Comment: @drescherjm it would seem that libcurl includes `windows.h`, which defines various things that are conflicting with other things that raylib declares using the same names.

Comment: Useful info: [How to tame the Windows headers (useful defines)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394910/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#define`s you mention are Win32 SDK defines.  They instruct `windows.h` (more accurately, various other Win32 headers that `windows.h` itself `#include`s) to not define/declare various symbols.

The `#define` you are looking for to omit a declaration of `PlaySound(A|W)` (in `mmsystem.h`) is:

```
#define MMNOSOUND
```

Here is the full table of defines in `mmsystem.h`:

```
 *  Define:         Prevent inclusion of:
 *  --------------  --------------------------------------------------------
 *  MMNODRV         Installable driver support
 *  MMNOSOUND       Sound support
 *  MMNOWAVE        Waveform support
 *  MMNOMIDI        MIDI support
 *  MMNOAUX         Auxiliary audio support
 *  MMNOMIXER       Mixer support
 *  MMNOTIMER       Timer support
 *  MMNOJOY         Joystick support
 *  MMNOMCI         MCI support
 *  MMNOMMIO        Multimedia file I/O support
 *  MMNOMMSYSTEM    General MMSYSTEM functions
```

Alternatively:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

Which will prevent `windows.h` from `#include`'ing a bunch of headers, including `mmsystem.h`.

[Where did WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN come from?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091130-00/?p=15863)